# XSL unique values per node per position

Tags: xslt, unique

this get ever more complicated :)

now i face another issue in last question we managed to take unique values from only one parent node

now with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<roots>
     <root>
          <name>first</name>
          <item>
               <something>A</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>B</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>C</something>
               <something>P</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>A</something>
               <something>L</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>A</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>B</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>D</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
     </root>
     <root>
          <name>second</name>
          <item>
               <something>E</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>B</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>F</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>A</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>A</something>
               <something>A</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>B</something>
               <something>H</something>
          </item>
          <item>
               <something>D</something>
               <something>G</something>
          </item>
     </root>
</roots>
```

now i need to get the unique values depending only from one node before but just from the elements on the second position

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:key name="item-by-value" match="something"
 use="concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))"/>
<xsl:key name="rootkey" match="root" use="name"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="key('rootkey','first')">
<xsl:for-each select="item/something[1]">
<xsl:sort />
  <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', 
                  concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))))">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> 
<xsl:text>_________</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="item/something[2]">
<xsl:sort />
  <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', 
                  concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))))">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with this XSL i get ABCD_________LP
where the result i need is ABCD_________ALP

any ideas?

Comment: (+1). See my answer for an easy modification of the solution I provided to your previous question. It's that easy. :)

Comment: @Nathan - Are you able to use xslt 2.0? If so, what processor are you using? (I couldn't find your other question; sorry if this was covered in that one.)

Comment: no, i can only use xslt 1.0 and i use Xalan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, the issue is that if you want to say "the first node with this content under this root *appearing in this position in the `item` node*", then you have to add "position in the `item` node" to the key.  You can either do this by having two separate keys, as Dimitre's solution does, or change your key to:

```
use="concat(normalize-space(.), ' ', 
     count(./preceding-sibling::something), ' ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))"/>
```

And then make your two test expressions look like:

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', 
              concat(normalize-space(.), ' 0 ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))))">
```

and:

```
<xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('item-by-value', 
              concat(normalize-space(.), ' 1 ', generate-id(./ancestor::root))))">
```

Comment: Reasonable. I hate making keys "too compound", so I'm using two simpler keys.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a slight modification to my answer to your previous question and you've got it!**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSomethingByNameAndVal-1" match="something[1]"
  use="concat(../../name, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:key name="kSomethingByNameAndVal-2" match="something[2]"
  use="concat(../../name, '+', .)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
     <xsl:for-each select=
      "item/something[1]
             [generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSomethingByNameAndVal-1',
                               concat(../../name, '+', .)
                              )
                          )
             ]
      ">

       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

     <xsl:for-each select=
      "item/something[2]
             [generate-id()
             =
              generate-id(key('kSomethingByNameAndVal-2',
                               concat(../../name, '+', .)
                              )
                          )
             ]
      ">

       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document, The wanted, correct results are produced**:

```
ABCD
APL
EBFAD
AHG
```

Comment: Oh, it's just once again: question from the same guy about xsl, same two people answer, once again your answer comes in while I'm typing mine, and the answers each of us gave to this question are very similar to what each of us gave to his earlier question.

Comment: hehe hey its good to have both approaches :) i will be generation the position depending on the number of root elements and i cant create key on the run so im using daniel's method .. still thank you very enlightening

Comment: @Daniel-Martin: Why, this is fun. Hope to meet you like this on SO many more times in the future! :) Glad we have similar interests.

Comment: @Daniel-Martin: Or you can drop me a line. I'm dnovatchev on 10^100's mail.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're restricted to XSLT 1.0 and you're using Xalan, but I'm going to add this answer just in case it might help someone else doing a search in the future. (That can use XSLT 2.0.) Hope you don't mind.

Also, I'm using Saxon-HE 9.2.0.6 for the processor.

Here's the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/roots">
      <xsl:for-each select="root">
         <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(item/something[1])"/>___<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(item/something[2])"/>
         <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the output using your XML:

```
A B C D___A P L
E B F A D___A H G
```

If you wanted to strip the spaces from the output, you could put the output in a variable and then use `replace` to strip the spaces. (Anyone know of a better way?)

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/roots">
      <xsl:variable name="output">
         <xsl:for-each select="root">
            <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(item/something[1])"/>___<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(item/something[2])"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace($output,' ','')"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
ABCD___APL
EBFAD___AHG
```